# Guessing best encoding from set for UTF-8 data in c#

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

I have text which is encoded in UTF-8, well formatted. I can't predict what languages the text will be in.

To print this text on a receipt thermal printer, I need to choose the best encoding to display the text with and convert to it. Unfortunately, UTF-8 is not supported. All available encodings can represent only a subset of characters.

So I would need to find the best option (e.g. from the list mentioned here https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=321) to convert the data too and lose as little characaters in the process (I am aware I will not be able to print Cyrillic together with Thai)

It is not a "guess the encoding" question, but rather choosing the best encoding for minimum loss of representable characters.

Has anybody seen a good approach?

Comment: Good question. Those are the character sets supported by your printer? My knee-jerk reaction is "get a better printer, one with Unicode support", but I guess that's not an option. I don't really see a good approach other than enumerate the available encodings (i.e., translate each of them into their Unicode Code Points once), and see which ones has the fewest "unprintables" for your given text.

Comment: UTF8 or 16 is the same to .NET - it's Unicode. Essentially, you are asking which *codepage* covers all or most of the characters in a Unicode string. Characters are grouped in blocks that more-or-less cover locales, so you could map block names to printer codepages

Comment: The list I linked is pretty much the industry standard, some might have an exotic code page in addition, some might miss a few. The business requirement is not surprisingly to re-use existing partner POS printers installed, so no control over devices.

Comment: Disregard the UTF-8/UTF-16 in .NET, doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: So is there a practical way the to map code pages to unicode blocks?

Comment: The problem is that the printer requires an "ESC R" sequence to switch to country specific characters set. If you want to print the maximum of UTF8 characters supported by the printer, you will have to introduce country  switch commands in the output.

Comment: More or less - the EPSON tables aren't that "standard", since many printers used custom character sets for local codepages and different fonts. Eg. the Greek standard is 921, yet old computers and printers would use 861, 850, 728. Moreover, a lot of the graphic characters in Latin1 occur in different places in different codepages

Comment: Graffito: I've already had issues issuing commands in the middle of output or lines, so I'll go with selecting one best match at the beginning and print the whole thing in one code page.